# What does "snowflake system" mean?

Tags: docker, deployment, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I am currently working on the topic of ci/cd. In one tutorial it is said that it is not desirable to create a **"snowflake system"**. What is the meaning of this?

Comment: Can you provide that reference? I don't know what this has to do with CI either, but I know that _snowball systems_ are undesirable :-D

Comment: @PMF :-) unfortunately, the tutorial is in german. i have marked the passage. https://youtu.be/eGQ5vrngBzs?t=143

Comment: I'm fluent in german, so that's not a problem. The problem is that he several times mentions "yesterdays video" but I can't find which video is the previous in their (quite long) list of broadcasts.

Comment: @PMF Cool! I also saw shortly afterwards that you are a CH'ler ;-) You are right. I'm watching the previous video right now. I hadn't seen that either. It's about XCOPY and that's something with windows. So it's not my topic. https://youtu.be/AFRsix3jHXU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [previous video](https://youtu.be/AFRsix3jHXU) (thanks for finding it) he defines the term: A *snowflake system* is a group of servers that are allegedly equal, but in reality are not. Because both the servers and the installed software is maintained and updated manually, their software starts to divert (e.g. some installation failed, some server was forgotten in a deployment round).

Snowflakes look identical from a distance, but they're never equal.

The concept (or bad practice, in this case) of manually deploying is of course not limited to the Windows command `xcopy`. Using linux equivalents doesn't help.

Comment: @MaikLowrey I do, but I'd rather not publicly link to it from here. Bad that SO isn't having any personal message option.

Comment: Yes, that's a real pity! Thanks and greetings

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Thanks to @PMF. PMF gave me the idea to watch a previous tutorial of this and so I found out what a snowflake server is. It's about the context of the deployment to different servers. And if you do the deployment with just copying files, there can be problems. Because each server is always unique. Like snowflakes in nature. They look the same but in detail they are different or unique.

So whoever is interested or if someone has the same question in the future. **This is it! :-)**